# Black Siren hair style change in Arrow Season 6 Episode 10

Tags: arrowverse, arrow

[image]

In S06E10 of Arrow, there were two scenes where black siren was shown and she had entirely different hairstyles. In one scene her hair was short and black whereas in another scene it was long and blond.How does her hair grow so fast and the hairstyle changes?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe she wasn't wearing a wig when it was long and blonde?

Comment: Her hairs are blond, she was wearing black wig when she had to seduce kill someone

Comment: Women Do have some fashion choices which often change in period of small time frame..

Comment: @AnkitSharma do you have any reference to that?

Comment: @Vishwa I watch that show regularly and she did wear that black wig previously too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma by wearing the black wig her hair became short too. I thought Katie Cassidy may have had some different hairstyle in some movie which is shown in the show.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Same here. but I was asking about the thing you mentioned above. you said **she was wearing black wig when she had to seduce kill someone**. Wearing wig once to seduce/kill doesn't make it a sure thing. So I was wondering if there's any official note there. Black siren is not very clear character.it'd help understand her better if there's some official info there. (not talking about wikis)

Comment: @codeczar do you know how wig works ? Mostly when you wear wig, your hairs get folded inside and then covered by wig. Legth can be increased or decreased easily

Comment: @Vishwa I don't think I can get any official wording that's why left a comment not answer.

Comment: @Vishwa the black wig seduction kill is in season 6 ep 4 "reversal"

Comment: @NikhilEshvar yes. but what I meant by my question, being on certain disguise **once** doesn't mean she always do the disguise for seduction/kill always. So I was wondering if it's some kindd of permanent thing with her. that using same disguise for similar task

Comment: Gotta watch the 10th episode for that! Will report once I watch it!

Comment: Since Black Siren is technically Laurel Lance, who is dead on this Earth, she wears a wig when going out in public to disguise herself. She did it in that episode where she picked up a guy in a bar and killed him in the alley. She did it here in 06x10 when accompanying Caden James to the port offices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, if you pay close attention to when she wears the black wig and when she doesn't, she only seems to wear the wig when she is doing underhanded shady stuff with Diaz. When she is around Quinten and the others, she doesn't wear the wig. It's all a part of keeping her cover.